# Colour transition and back to original colour not working correctly

Tags: android, animation

I am currently working on an Android app and I am trying to get a colour animation to work.

Basically I have a LinearLayout that contains various componenets and when a certain event happens, I want the LinearLayout background colour quickly flash red.

I have an animation set up which I am trying to animate the colour so it fades in to the red then fades back out again. However, for some reason, there doesn't seem to be any animation when the colour first appears, only when it is fading back out again.

Below is my drawable:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparentColour" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/errorColour" />
</transition>
```

Below is how I am doing my transition:

```
TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = (TransitionDrawable)linearLayoutPlatform.getBackground();
                transitionDrawable.startTransition(2000);
                transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reversing the transition immediately, so the initial transition is being canceled.

```
transitionDrawable.startTransition(2000);
linearLayoutPlatform.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(2000);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was thinking the startTransition would be blocking so it would until complete then the next line would get run. Thinking about it though makes sense its not a blocking function